# jQuery-ui-draggable convert pixel value to percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

How to convert `ui.position.top` value to percentage when setting
 `data-offset` property.

```
.draggable({
    scroll: false,
    axis: "y",
    drag: function (event, ui) {
        y1 = $parent.height();//height of the parent elem
        y2 = $elem.height(); //height of the elem that is being dragged
        if (ui.position.top >= 0) {
            ui.position.top = 0;
        } else if (ui.position.top <= (y1 - y2)) {
            ui.position.top = y1 - y2;
        }
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        //convert value to percentage and set prop.
        $('.cover').attr('data-offset', ui.offset.top);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  function topToPerc(t, p, round) {
    var result = 0;
    if (round == undefined) {
      result = parseFloat(((t / p) * 100).toFixed(2));
    } else {
      result = Math.round((t / p) * 100);
    }
    return result;
  }

  $(".box").each(function(i, el) {
    if (i != 2) {
      $("p", el).html(topToPerc($(el).position().top, $(".page").height()) + "%");
    } else {
      $("p", el).html(topToPerc($(el).position().top, $(".page").height(), true) + "%");
    }
  });

  $(".box").draggable({
    axis: "y",
    containment: [0, 0, 350, 200],
    drag: function(e, ui) {
      if ($(this).index() != 2) {
        $("p", this).html(topToPerc(ui.position.top, $(".page").height()) + "%");
      } else {
        $("p", this).html(topToPerc(ui.position.top, $(".page").height(), true) + "%");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body,
.page {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.page {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}

.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 2em;
  position: absolute;
}

.box p {
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="page">
  <div class="box ui-widget-content" style="top: 10px; left: 8px; background: #fcc;">
    <p></p>
  </div>

  <div class="box ui-widget-content" style="top: 175px; left: 160px; background: #cfc;">
    <p></p>
  </div>

  <div class="box ui-widget-content" style="top: 200px; left: 312px; background: #ccf;">
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your post did not include a complete example. So I am not sure what you are trying to look for. As you can see, this shows the percentage based on the height. You might also consider using a modified Slider: https://jqueryui.com/slider/#slider-vertical

**Update**

Adjusted containment and the function. Now it accepts a `top` value and a parent `height` value and calculates the percentage.

Comment: When moving the object around, draggable widget appends the current position value to target element, any way to obtain that value and convert that to % and append that to  `$('.cover')`? I tried both answers (including  @Souleste), the value given appears off e.g. when I drag target elem all the way down within parent, the value should be close -100% but its around -50%. May be better fetching the value that draggable widget appends inline to the target elem when dragging and convert that to percentage? e.g. `<img ... style="left: 0px;top: -382.406px;">`<-- appended by draggable

Comment: @JamieWhite You can do this with `ui.position.top`; yet it should be relative percentage to parent or document or window? `$('.cover')` is undefined in your post.

Comment: Parent. .cover is a div with some text

Comment: @JamieWhite updated the answer to fit your needs better. Since you did not provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example ( https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ), I have no reference for any of the HTML. I don't know what `$(".cover")` is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you are looking for position from the top of the document:

```
$('.cover').attr('data-offset', Math.ceil(ui.offset.top / $parent.height() * 100));
```

And this if you are looking for position from the top of the parent:

```
$('.cover').attr('data-offset', Math.ceil(ui.position.top / $parent.height() * 100));
```